# How to exclude a folder in a working git repository (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code version 0.7.10. I want to use version control. I figured this was a good time to start teaching myself to use git. I have never used it before.

How do I make git ignore my "node_modules" folder? Every item in this folder is listed for possible commits and that is cluttering up my workspace. I don't want to upload all the packages. I figure whoever runs the package.json can do that on their own computer.

Thought: I found under **File > Preferences > User Settings** that there is a configuration file called "settings.json" that will overwrite the default settings. I see a "Git configuration" in the default settings but I can't find any documentation on my possible options here. I would think I could do a "git.exclude" but where do I begin. This is only a guess at a solution. I am sure the real answer is something completely different.

I am looking for any documentation you could point me to. Thanks!

UPDATE: I made a change to the ".git/info/exclude" file and my Git repository view cleared up instantly. Here is a link that talks about the exclude file and why it worked for my VS Code editor. (https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)

Comment: I'm in almost the same boat, except that I want to even do the most simple of things, store the code on my visual studio online tfs instance. And what you said is correct: where is the documentation about how to do that with VSCode?

Comment: I hear you. I wish it had TFS integration. I would have used that first. I already have my other files in TFS. I checked on the forums for MS and I don't see anything about integrating VSCode with TFS. Seems like a missed opportunity to me. This is a version 0.7.0 software so maybe they will get a clue and offer some more options later. If you see something in the future I would be interested.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In git you can always use **.gitignore** to make git ignore some files.
You can find the documentation here : http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Thanks for the post. This was most helpful. I actually have an exclude file under my project "...\.git\info\exclude". I added the pattern `node_modules/` and it removed all those files from my Git integration with VS Code instantly! My project looks a lot cleaner now.

Comment: Even if it's a better practice to use a  .gitignore file than an external ignore file. This data must live in the repository...

Comment: Great point Philippe. I found this link that talks about why my exclude file method worked. I wish I had found this link the other day but oh well now it makes more sense (https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/). My Editor is integrated with Git so the exclude seems like an okay choice in this situation. I am learning Git and Github so this is all part of the learning process. I appreciate the input.

Comment: `.gitignore` for VSCode: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/VisualStudioCode.gitignore

Comment: If you want this configuration across all projects associated with your github account try a global config like `core.excludesfile` ( Doc - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration )

[ full answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/72322460/5070253 ]

Answer (score 45):

Follow the steps to add a folder to .gitignore using UI

1. Click Source Control on left pane
2. Click on three dots at right top of Source Control tab
3. Select View & Sort>View as Tree
4. Right click on the folder you want to add to .gitignore
5. Select Add to .gitignore

You are done!

Comment: Hi in my case "Add to .gitignore" creates new .gitignore file outside the main project folder. Don't add the in .gitignore file already created in root directory.

Comment: this added all the inner files, edited gitignore manually instead just using the folder

Answer (score 30):

You can use this setting:

```
"git.ignoredRepositories": []
```

which specifically does what you're asking. This won't pollute your .gitignore file if the only thing you want to do is to exclude a folder from vscode git but not from git itself. For example, this is useful if your home dir is under version control, since thousands of files would have to be ignored otherwise, which is hardly what you want.

Comment: +1 This is a very nice solution if you don't want VS Code to track any changes to project files (e.g. .xcworkspace) but those files will remain in git.

Comment: Great! This should be the accepted answer! Thank you!

Comment: I am proposing a change in the Question title, as the body does not match the question. Original question:
- "Exclude folder from git in Visual Studio Code"
-> where the correct answer is "git.ignoredRepositories": []

However the body of the question is related to "how to use git" rather than how to filter a git repository in VS Code. If approved, I would see how to post the question again and move this answer there.

Answer (score 26):

You would make a .gitignore file in the base directory of your git repository and add any files or folders that you would like to ignore. In your case your file would contain

```
/node_modules/
```

Documentation: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 8):

Github maintain a [repository containing .gitignore files](https://github.com/github/gitignore) for a lot of languages.

[Here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore) is the one you need for Node...

Or you could generate one (very useful if you use different technologies in the same repository) using the web site: http://gitignore.io

Ps: Except if you've got really good reasons (exclude rules that you want to keep only for you), don't use `.git/info/exclude` to ignore files but prefer to use and commit the `.gitignore` file (to share it with all repository users).

Answer (score 8):

This is an old solved question, but for anyone else who is still struggling with the accepted (and correct) answer, you literally need to add a file to your main (ie root) project folder called:

.gitignore

If you add helloworld.gitignore it won't work. Or whywontthiswork.gitignore, etc. It must be .gitignore.

Inside the file, type this text:

/node_modules

Assuming your placement of the .gitignore file is at the same relative path of the node_modules folder, anything in node_modules will be excluded from change tracking.

Comment: Hi in my case "Add to .gitignore" creates new .gitignore file outside the main project folder. Don't add the in .gitignore file already created in root directory.

Answer (score 8):

There is a simple way to do this.

```
git rm <file-name>
git commit -m '<message>'
git push
```

for folders,

```
git rm -r <folder-name>/*
git commit -m '<message>'
git push
```

Comment: This will remove files from the system

Answer (score 5):

Create a file with **.gitignore** & put the folder or file name which one you want to ignore.

**to ignore everything below node_modules folder**

```
echo node_modules/ > .gitignore
```

Answer (score 4):

To exclude a folder from git across all projects on your machine, you can use  `core.excludesfile` configuration [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Create a file called `~/.gitignore_global` then add files or folders you would like to exclude like `node_modules` or editor folders like `.vscode`

Then run:
`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to exclude a file vie private ignore using `.git/info/exclude`. In my case VSCode still kept it as tracked and listed. Even `git rm -f --cached <filename>` didn't helped at all.

What helped instantly was the extension named [GIT-EXCLUDE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=boukichi.git-exclude)
Just had to install it and as I had the file alredy in the exclude file it disappeared right in the moment when the extension started.

It also allows you to use RMB in VSCode file explorer to exclude files conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers pointing you to make a `.gitignore` file...

As a good starting point for any `.gitignore` file, you can search at https://gitignore.io. Specific settings for 'VisualStudioCode' and various other tools and languages can be entered, and the site will generate a .gitignore file for you.

Additional points

- You can add a `.gitignore` to any folder to create entries specific to that folder and its nested folders as well.
- By default, Git will not save an empty folder. You can put an empty `.gitignore` file into a folder to force git to save it.

Answer (score 1):

On your `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` add:

```js
"files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/Thumbs.db": true,
        "_ide_helper_models.php": true,
        "_ide_helper*.php": true,
        ".vscode": true,
        ".git/logs": true,
        ".git": true,
        "**/.idea": true,
        ".idea": true,
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you ignore any file without using the shared `.gitignore` file (**recommended for sharing**).

```
nano ~/.gitignore_global
```

This creates a global file where you can put files you always ignore, like `.vscode` or `.DS_Store`.

You can add the names of files/folders you want to ignore in the file, and save it.

And then you can run

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

To configure the created file into git.