# How to ignore outside libraries git status from source control in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

When using cloned C library which is outside of project workspace, if I look these library's header files by using navigation, VSCode shows library's git status also even if I don't have interest about library's status. This is very annoying for me.

How to suppress this unnecessary reference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084281/exclude-folder-from-git-in-visual-studio-code is this approach not working?

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries are git repository, selecting `false` for Git: Auto Repository Detection suppress unnecessary repository detection.